# $\operatorname{Lk}(C_1,C_2)= \operatorname{Lk}(C_2,C_1)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory

> Let $D$ be an oriented link diagram with two components $C_1,C_2$. Then $\operatorname{Lk}(C_1,C_2)= \operatorname{Lk}(C_2,C_1)$.

By definition of Linking number is the following:

> The linking number of $\operatorname{Lk}(C_1,C_2)$ is defined to be $[C_2] = \operatorname{Lk}(C_1,C_2)\cdot\mu_1\in H_1(S^3\setminus C_1)\simeq\Bbb Z=\langle\mu_1\rangle$.

I also have a pictorial definition (maybe same as wikipedia says). From that pictorial definition, the above statement is obvious. But from the definition using homology, it's not very obvious to me. How can I show they are the same numbers? * I know the concept of meridian

Note. I'm not very familiar with knot theory. I only know homology theory (Hatcher AT Chapter 2 level). That linking number definition is the first nontrivial definition I met.

Answer (score 5):

The function $\operatorname{Lk(C_1,-)}$ that takes oriented curves in the complement of $C_1$ to the linking number can thought of as being comprised of two steps: (1) take the image of the second curve in $H_1(S^3\setminus C_1)$ and then (2) apply the isomorphism $H_1(S^3\setminus C_1)\to\mathbb{Z}$ given by the meridian $\mu_1$ of $C_1$.

The universal coefficient theorem lets us think of this isomorphism as being an element $\mu_1^*$ of $H^1(S^3\setminus C_1)$, hence we can think of the linking number in terms of the canonical pairing between $H^1(S^3\setminus C_1)$ and $H_1(S^3\setminus C_1)$, with $\operatorname{Lk}(C_1,C_2) = \langle \mu_1^*,[C_2]\rangle$.  My goal is to transform this until it is obviously symmetric, though we will also see it is symmetric along the way to this destination.  I should say that I don't feel like I succeeded in making it completely obvious, but by the end we more or less see why it calculates the Gauss linking integral.

Where does this $\mu_1^*$ element come from, though? It's Alexander duality: $H_1(C_1) \cong H^1(S^3\setminus C_1)$, and $\mu_1^*$ is the image of the fundamental class of $C_1$ (the one that gives $C_1$ its orientation).  Let's recall how this isomorphism works.  Let $\nu C_1\subseteq S^3$ denote an open tubular neighborhood of $C_1$, and let $S^3-C_1$ denote the closed manifold $S^3\setminus\nu C_1$.  First of all, there is a relative cap product
$$\frown:H_3(S^3-C_1,\partial(S^3-C_1))\otimes H^1(S^3-C_1) \to H_2(S^3-C_1,\partial(S^3-C_1))$$
and second of all there is a long exact sequence
$$\cdots \to H_2(S^3) \to H_2(S^3,C_1) \xrightarrow{\partial} H_1(C_1) \to H_1(S^3) \to \cdots$$
Recall that $H_2(S^3,C_1)\cong H_2(S^3-C_1,\partial(S^3-C_1))$ by excision along with the fact that the closure of $\nu C_1$ is a collar neighborhood of $C_1$.  Let $[S^3]\in H_3(S^3)$ be the fundamental class.  The image of this in $H_3(S^3,C_1)\cong H_3(S^3-C_1,\partial(S^3-C_1))$ is the fundamental class of $S^3-C_1$, so we will identify them.  Then Alexander duality is the map
\begin{align*}
D: H^1(S^3\setminus C_1) &\to H_1(C_1) \\
\alpha &\mapsto \partial([S^3] \frown \alpha)
\end{align*}
Let's work through the inverse to identify $\mu_1^*$.  Given the fundamental class $[C_1]\in H_1(C_1)$, then since $H_1(S^3)=H_2(S^3)=0$, there is a unique class $[\Sigma_1]\in H_2(S^3,C_1)$ whose boundary is $[C_1]$.  (By the way, we can represent the 2-cycle $\Sigma_1$ by an oriented embedded surface -- this is a *Seifert surface* for $C_1$.  One reason Seifert surfaces are important is that they demarcate when you've gone around $C_1$.)  We now want to solve the equation $[S^3]\frown\alpha=[\Sigma_1]$ for some $1$-cocycle $\alpha$.  Recall that when $\beta\in H^2(S^3-C_1,\partial(S^3-C_1))$,
$$\langle \beta,[\Sigma_1]\rangle = \langle \beta, [S^3]\frown\alpha\rangle = \langle \alpha\smile\beta, [S^3]\rangle$$
Since this holds for all $\beta$, this is saying that $\alpha$ must be the Poincaré dual of $[\Sigma_1]$.  We can give a concrete description of the Poincaré dual: $\mu_1^*$ is the class such that $\langle \mu_1^*,[C_2]\rangle=\Sigma_1\cdot C_2$ for all oriented curves $C_2$ in the complement of $C_1$, where $\Sigma_1\cdot C_2$ is the algebraic intersection number, which we can define by
$$\Sigma_1\cdot C_2 = \langle PD(\Sigma_1)\smile PD(C_2),[S^3]\rangle$$
where $PD$ denotes the Poincaré dual.  Geometrically, it's the count of the signed intersections between $\Sigma_1$ and $C_2$ after they've been perturbed to lie transverse to one another.  Incidentally, by taking $\Sigma_1$ to be the canonical Seifert surface given a diagram of $C_1$, you can check that this calculates the linking number defined by a signed count of crossings between $C_1$ and $C_2$ in the diagram.  Given this, we might say we're done because that signed count is obviously symmetric.

Let $[\Sigma_2]\in H_2(S^3,C_2)$ represent the Alexander dual of $[C_2]\in H_1(C_2)$.  We now have
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Lk}(C_1,C_2) &= \Sigma_1 \cdot \partial \Sigma_2 \\
&= \langle PD(\Sigma_1) \smile PD(\partial\Sigma_2), [S^3]\rangle \\
&= \langle PD(\Sigma_1) \smile \delta PD(\Sigma_2), [S^3]\rangle \\
&= \langle \mu_1^* \smile \delta \mu_2^*, [S^3]\rangle
\end{align*}
where the last line is using the definition $\mu_i^*=PD(\Sigma_i)$.

The cup product $\mu_1^*\smile \mu_2^*$ is an element of $H^2(S^3,C_1\cup C_2)$, and with it we can perform the following calculation:
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Lk}(C_1,C_2) - \operatorname{Lk}(C_2,C_1)
&= \langle \mu_1^* \smile \delta \mu_2^*, [S^3]\rangle - \langle \mu_2^* \smile \delta \mu_1^*, [S^3]\rangle \\
&= \langle \mu_1^* \smile \delta \mu_2^*, [S^3]\rangle - \langle \delta\mu_1^* \smile \mu_2^*, [S^3]\rangle \\
&= \langle \delta(\mu_1^* \smile \mu_2^*), [S^3]\rangle \\
&= \langle \mu_1^* \smile \mu_2^*, \partial[S^3]\rangle \\
&= \langle \mu_1^* \smile \mu_2^*, 0\rangle \\
&= 0
\end{align*}
Therefore the linking number is symmetric!

Let's take a moment to consider what $\delta(\mu_1^* \smile \mu_2^*)$ is.  Applying Poincaré duals, this is $PD(\partial(\Sigma_1\cdot\Sigma_2))$.  The algebraic intersection of $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ is calculated by putting the surfaces into general position and taking the oriented intersection, which is a bunch of arcs and circles.  The boundary of a circle is $0$, but the boundary of an arc is the difference of the endpoints, which is $0$ in $H_0(S^3\setminus C_1\cup C_2)$ since the space is connected.

I've still only showed that the linking number is symmetric, but I promised putting it into a form where it is obviously symmetric.  Let $\Delta\subseteq S^3\times S^3$. Inside $H^3(S^3\times S^3,S^3\times S^3\setminus\Delta)$ is a unique class $u$ (essentially the Thom class) that has to do with local orientation of $S^3$, which we can define in a relatively concrete way.  Since $S^3$ is parallelizable, we can parameterize a closed tubular neighborhood of $\Delta$ as $S^3\times B^3$, and thus by applying excision,
$$H^3(S^3\times S^3,S^3\times S^3\setminus\Delta) \cong H^3(S^3\times S^3,S^3\times S^3-\Delta) \cong H^3(S^3\times B^3, S^3\times S^2)$$
This is isomorphic to $H_3(S^3\times B^3)$ by Poincaré duality, and since $S^3\times B^3$ deformation retracts onto $S^3$, we see the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.  Using $[S^3]\in H_3(S^3)$, then let $u$ be the corresponding class in $H^3(S^3\times S^3,S^3\times S^3\setminus\Delta)$.  ​On relative $3$-cycles $\gamma$, its defining formula is
$$\langle u, \gamma\rangle = \Delta_*([S^3])\cdot\gamma$$
That is, it's the algebraic intersection number with the diagonal.  Related to this is the useful formula
$$\langle u \smile (\alpha\times\beta),[S^3\times S^3]\rangle = \langle \alpha\smile \beta, [S^3]\rangle$$
So, for example,
$$\langle u, \Sigma_1\times C_2\rangle = \Sigma_1\cdot C_2$$

For this next part, I'm going to use a trick to simplify the explanation.  If we remove a point from $S^3$, then linking number calculations essentially don't change.  Let $u'\in H^3(\mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}^3-\Delta)$ be the restriction of $u$.  Consider the long exact sequence
$$\cdots \to H^2(\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3) \to H^2(\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3-\Delta) \xrightarrow{\delta} H^3(\mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}^3-\Delta) \to H^3(\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3) \to \cdots$$
Since the outer two cohomology groups are trivial, $\delta$ is an isomorphism, so we can pull the class we found back to a unique class $\alpha\in H^2(\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3-\Delta)$ with $\delta\alpha=u'$.  Thus,
$$\langle u', \Sigma_1\times C_2\rangle = \langle \delta\alpha, \Sigma_1\times C_2\rangle = \langle \alpha, \partial(\Sigma_1 \times C_2)\rangle = \langle \alpha, C_1\times C_2\rangle$$
(This is also, equivalently, $\langle \alpha\smile (\mu_1^*\times\mu_2^*),[S^3\times S^3] \rangle$.)

Therefore, there is this $\alpha\in H^2(\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3-\Delta)$ that does not depend on $C_1$ or $C_2$ such that
$$\operatorname{Lk}(C_1,C_2) = \langle\alpha, C_1\times C_2\rangle$$
I'm not sure the best way to see this is symmetric directly, but one way is to go back to 1833 and take a page from Gauss's *die Anzahl der Umschlingungen* in *Nachlass zur Electrodynamic* where he gives the integral
$$ \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{S^1\times S^1} \frac{\gamma_1(s)-\gamma_2(t)}{\lvert \gamma_1(s)-\gamma_2(t)\lvert^3} \cdot (\gamma_1'(s)\times\gamma_2'(t))\,ds\,dt $$
where $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are differentiable parameterizations of $C_1$ and $C_2$.  Using $\mathbb{R}$ coefficients (and the isomorphism to de Rham cohomology), we can represent $\alpha$ by the closed $2$-form $\omega$ on $\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3-\Delta$ given by
$$\omega(v,w) = \frac{1}{4\pi\lvert x-y \rvert^3}\det(x-y,v,w)$$
where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^3$ parameterize $\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3-\Delta$.  We can check that $\omega$ is closed and that it calculates the linking number of a Hopf link, so it *must* represent $\alpha$ since $H^2(\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3-\Delta;\mathbb{R})$ is $1$-dimensional.
Hence,
$$\operatorname{Lk}(C_1,C_2) = \langle\alpha, C_1\times C_2\rangle = \int_{C_1\times C_2}\omega$$
We can see that $\omega_{y,x}(w,v)=\omega_{x,y}(v,w)$ since a double negative cancels out, so
$$\operatorname{Lk}(C_2,C_1) = \int_{C_2\times C_1}\omega = \int_{C_1\times C_2}\omega = \operatorname{Lk}(C_1,C_2)$$
and we see the linking number is symmetric.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's much harder than I thought using cohomology theory. Unfortunately, I don't know cohomology theory yet. So I'll accept the answer after I learn cohomology theory and actually understand your answer.  But I'll up vote your answer instead.

Comment: That's fantastic. I ll make sure to come here again to understand your answer after I have learnt some more

Answer (score 2):

In my other answer, I use (co)homology and dualities to show this definition of linking number is symmetric - it's something I had worked out before and this was a good opportunity to write it down.

However, the question really only was "why is the homological definition the same as the diagram-based definition."  Here's how I've thought about it.  We're going to take the image of $C_2$ in $H_1(S^3\setminus C_1)$.

First, take a diagram of $C_1$ and $C_2$. Second, "lift" the $C_2$ part above the plane of the diagram, where when there's a part of $C_2$ that lies under $C_1$, add in line segments to detour under $C_1$ (this is illustrated below).  The lifted curve is homologous to the original curve because it's homotopic, but it's also easy to work out what boundaries of 2-chains you're adding in to make this happen.  Third, at the places where $C_2$ still goes under $C_1$, add in the boundary of a 2-chain to "bubble off" a loop around $C_1$.

[image: lifting and "bubbling off"]

This shows the 2-chain whose boundary, when added in, bubbles off the loop:

[image: adding in a boundary to bubble off]

After bubbling off the loops, the remaining part of $C_2$ above the diagram lies in a subspace homeomorphic to an open ball $B$.  Recall that $H_1(B)=0$, so this means this part of $C_2$ is nullhomologous in $B$ (i.e., it is the boundary of a 2-chain in $B$), so it is the boundary of a 2-chain in $S^3\setminus C_1$ and can be removed.

All that's left are these rings on $C_1$.  If you are familiar with those "bead maze" toys for babies, the principle is now very similar: take all of the loops ("beads") and drag them along $C_1$ until they are co-located.  Unlike beads in a bead maze, loops have an orientation.  If two of the loops have opposite orientation, they cancel out.  What's left after cancellation is some multiple of $\mu_1$, and if you think through what we did, the coefficient in front of $\mu_1$ is the number of positive crossings where $C_2$ goes under $C_1$ minus the number of negative crossings where $C_2$ goes under $C_1$.  That matches Wikipedia's formula $\operatorname{Lk}(C_1,C_2)=n_1-n_4$ for linking number!

---

Side note: I'll take a moment to illustrate what the relation is between this and Alexander duality in the other answer.  If you lift up $C_2$ (letting it pass through $C_1$!) up above the plane of the diagram, then it is nullhomologous using a 2-chain in the ball $B$ that contains it.  Adding this to the 2-chains involved in the lift, we get a 2-chain $\Sigma_2$ in $S^3$ whose boundary is $C_2$.  Notice that with this setup, $C_1$ intersects $\Sigma_2$ exactly where we'd be bubbling off loops:

[image: relation to Alexander duality]

Pretty much the entire idea is that to account for the bubbled off loops, you can instead calculate the algebraic intersection number between $C_1$ and $\Sigma_2$.  Algebraic intersection number in this exemplary situation is from taking an oriented basis of tangent vectors of $\Sigma_2$ at the intersection along with the tangent vector of $C_1$ at the intersection, then taking the sign of the determinant of the $3\times 3$ matrix of these vectors.  This number tells you whether it's a $\mu_1$ or a $-\mu_1$ that bubbles off.